# Mysql Stored Procedure per connection or per transaction for thread safe

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, stored-procedures

First let me describe the problem I am facing.

We are developing a web service using Jersey and MySQL at back-end. It's simple that user can view or edit data via Restful API, and the service will load/save data to or from MySQL database.

I created several stored procedure at MySQL server, like SelectAnswer and UpdateAnswer. In the program, we use standard JDBC and MySQL connector to connect to the database.

Firstly I created stored procedure per connection. Like each time the program start a new connection to the database, it creates a bunch of Stored Procedure.

```
    public enum JDBCDataSource {
     INSTANCE;
     private BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
     private Connection conn;
     private CallableStatement answerUpsert;
     private JDBCDataSource(){
     initConnection();
     try{
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        answerUpsert = prepareSP(answerUpsert,"{call upsert_answer(?, ?, ?)}");
     } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

And the program reuse the stored procedure for each time calling:

```
private void executeUpsert(String app, String id, String content)
      throws SQLException{
try {
  CallableStatement callableStatement = JDBCDataSource.INSTANCE.getUpsert();
  callableStatement.setString(1,app);
  callableStatement.setInt(2,Integer.valueOf(id));
  callableStatement.setString(3,content);
  callableStatement.execute();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  callableStatement.clearParameters();
}
}
```

So each time calling the procedure, the function set its own parameters, and execute the SP, and finally clear the parameters.

But it is not thread safe, if the user post two request and one request is trying to set parameters, and another to clear parameters, it will cause an exception.

So for stored procedure in MySQL, should I create it per transaction or per connection in order to keep it thread safe? Maybe my understanding of SP and MySQL is not correct, or maybe it is design problem. Please share your though for my question.

Comment: "Maybe my understanding of SP and MySQL is not correct, or maybe it is design problem." +1 for both of those. Your `JDBCDataSource` is unnecessary, you only need a `DataSource` that can provide you a `Connection` and use that. Separate connections and statements for each threads.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What do you mean by separate connection for each thread, like each connection for each thread? What if I have 50 threads, then I need 50 different connections?  And for each thread I need to create its own statements?

Comment: You don't need to think of threads when you use a connection pool, have methods that retrieve a connection from the pool, create a callable statement and use it, then return the connection back to pool. Everything is contained nicely inside methods, so you can call them without worrying about threads getting mixed up with each other's resources. You've tried to go for a clever solution without really understanding how those resources work. Don't try to be too clever, do it the regular way. If you find problems with that, then ask for help.